# What does "Invalid parameter error. 0x80030057 (STG_E_INVALIDPARAMETER)" usually mean?

Tags: com, parameters, com-interop, hresult

I came across the COM error:

> Invalid parameter error. HRESULT 0x80030057 (STG_E_INVALIDPARAMETER)

when dealing with an Excel interop component called Aspose and couldn't figure out why this error when opening an Excel file. Nor could I find anything here on Stack Overflow so it MUST be asked:

What is the most common cause of this error (in any printed representation) from some black-box COM component?

I will also post what caused my error when SO allows me to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the cause was that I had targeted my C#.NET app that was interacting with a wrapped COM component (Aspose Excel 2.9.2) to run on "any CPU" platform. This is no good as the DLL was compiled explicitly for 32-bit platforms only. So my C#.NET app had to be platform targeted explicitly to "x86".

I'm not sure if this would be the most common though, but it's a pretty well obscured problem for that error message.

Comment: Updated detail of Aspose Excel version in response to @shahzad-latif

Comment: Marking as answer because no others provided and this "32-bit subcomponent running in any/64-bit mode instead of explicitly in 32-bit mode" is the most common cause I've seen.

Answer (score -1):

[Aspose file format products](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.total-for-.net/default.aspx) are not COM components. They're fully managed .NET assemblies. Could you please share which component caused this problem. Also, share the version number of the component you're using. I would also like to share that all the Aspose components work on 32-bit and 64-bit systems seamlessly. Also, they do not require MS Office to be installed on your development or deployment machines. Moreover, they do not use COM interop.

Please share some more details regarding your issue. You can also post your query along with all the details in our [support forums](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/default.aspx), so that our team would be able to investigate your issue in detail.

Disclosure: I work as a developer evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Thanks for your advice Shahzad. I have updated my posted answer. Please consider changing your answer into a comment on my post, as it doesn't answer the question asked.